# Problemas con script de webFlow en Next.js

Tags: reactjs, script, next.js

Hola buenos dias tengo el inconveniente de que quiero hacer una pagina en next.js y me estan pasando el sitio desde webFlow ya tengo todo creo solo que me encontre con un problema, no se me estan viendo las animaciones desde el sitio el problema lo tengo que no me esta cargando un script de tercero. tengo el siguiente codigo en mi Layout.tsx

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}

        <Script
          src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=6579dfa98e58d2fd99630b30"
          type="text/javascript"
          integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        ></Script>

        <Script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        ></Script>

        <Script src="/js/animation1.js"></Script>
        <Script src="/js/animation4.js"></Script>
        <Script src="/js/jaimeai.js"></Script>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

y el script que no me esta reconociendo es el de https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=6579dfa98e58d2fd99630b30 alguien a tenido este problema antes o sabe como lo puedo solucionar si quiero aplicar la estrategia de strategy="beforeInteractive" me fallan las animaciones el error que me tira en consola es el siguiente
Uncaught TypeError: pt is not a function at jaimeai.js:22:116

Muchas gracias